# RealmAdapter issues

Tags: android, realm

I am using the RealmAdapter but running into 2 major issues:

1. With automaticUpdate set to true, any changes to realm objects in getView causes an infinite loop with the list constantly being refreshed.
2. I have set transient properties on my objects using the @Ignore annotation. However, even with automaticUpdate set to false, these transient values are lost - i am not sure why - it may be the setting of other transient properties. Note that no other changes are made to the realm objects during this time.

Any suggestions to fix would be appreciated please. Thx.

Comment: `any changes to realm objects in getView `. Do any of these views have change listeners? like `CheckBox` for example.

Comment: @AhmedKhalaf No, none have change listeners

Comment: It is hard to tell what is going on without any code. Can you show your adapter and how it gets populated?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I have replaced the RealmAdapter with a normal ArrayAdapter and also transferred the content of the RealmResults to an ArrayList (since one cannot turn off auto updates on RealmResults). The code works perfectly now.

Answer (score -2):

The issue turned out to be the setting of transient properties when using RealmAdapter - this causes an infinite loop as RealmAdapter refreshes with each change but also discarding transient property values in the process. In the end I had to switch to a normal ArrayAdapter populated with a normal ArrayList.

We chose Realm for our Android project as we read good things about it and they advertise it as ***"Realm is a mobile database: a replacement for SQLite & Core Data.***" For Android at least, this is simply not true - it's limitations at this point prevent it from being considered a database in the traditional sense. Using it has been a painful and time consuming affair.

Limitations and annoyances:

1. No relationship management (its up to you to code for establishing and managing relationships). This gets complicated very quickly. Realm does not mention this material limitation anywhere on their site we could find.
2. No overrides/custom code in your model classes.
3. Inability to get a query result (RealmResults) which does not constantly update itself.
4. Bugs - see above and github.
5. Completely convoluted query syntax. Support for basic syntax like IN missing. No diacritic insensitive searches.
6. Transaction clauses.
7. Inadequate documentation.

On the positive side, using it is still easier than the dog's breakfast that is Android's implementation of SQLite.

Comment: I am sorry you feel that way. Can you elaborate on what documentation is missing?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Examples in general, but particularly to construct queries - in general and especially across relationships would be very helpful. I also think you need to be more explicit about the limitations at the start of the docs.

Comment: We actually just added a section about link queries yesterday: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries, which was indeed missing as you point out. We have some examples in our repo: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples, what do you feel is missing from them?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I downloaded the sample code when I started with Realm - but it would not compile at the time due to a dependency not having been updated. I tried a week later again with no success. I think i filed a bug on your github account about it.

Comment: Use of an ORM like [JDXA](http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/jdxa.html) on top of SQLite can turn a dog's breakfast into a delicious meal! Here are some [tasty bites](http://softwaretree.com/v1/products/jdxa/code-snippets.html).